# Use loops to define vast enums in TYpeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to use loops to define especially vast enums in typescript? What would be a proper way anyway?

Comment: I don't think so. If you have executable code, that automatically shifts it to runtime and TS *doesn't exist* at runtime. The type system is there only at compile time. I don't think TS can actually evaluate simple code like a loop and take it into account when compiling. Perhaps it would help if you give examples of what you're trying to do - there might be a different way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. But you need to first start seeing your project code in two different categories.

1. Code that you write
2. Code that you generate from the code you write (Because you're lazy/smart)

Once you made that division you can delegate a folder for your generated code which then is run in your build (package.json script or however you like to build your project). This ensures that when someone else pulls down your repo they can generate the required code automatically.

For generating the code, there are multiple ways:

1. Use `fs` and do it all yourself
2. Use templating engines like ejs but still too much work
3. Use the TypeScript Compiler API which is nice but it's a tad too complex
4. Use a library called ts-morph which makes working with TS Compiler API way easier.

I will show you the fourth way:

```
import { EnumDeclaration, Project, StructureKind } from "ts-morph";

export interface ICreateEnumParams {
  path: string;
  data: Record<string, string>;
  enumName: string;
}

export class EnumFactory {
  private project = new Project();
  private sourceFile = this.project.createSourceFile(this.params.path, "", {
    overwrite: true
  });

  constructor(private params: ICreateEnumParams) {}

  public async creareEnum(): Promise<void> {
    this.addMembers();
    await this.project.save();
  }

  private addMembers(): void {
    const enumDec = this.addEnum();
    Object.entries(this.params.data).forEach(entry =>
      enumDec.addMember({
        kind: StructureKind.EnumMember,
        name: entry[0],
        value: entry[1]
      })
    );
  }

  private addEnum(): EnumDeclaration {
    return this.sourceFile.addEnum({
      name: this.params.enumName,
      kind: StructureKind.Enum
    });
  }
}

async function run(): Promise<void> {
  const factory = new EnumFactory({
    path: "example.enum.ts",
    enumName: "MyEnum",
    data: { apple: "Apple", orange: "Orange" }
  });
  await factory.creareEnum();
}

run().catch(e => {
  throw new Error(e);
});
```

If you don't want to generate string enums and only standard ones, then just omit `value: entry[1]`. Probably would be best to extend the factory params to accept the enumType so you can create both types easily.